# Trigonometric identity $2\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) = \cos(\alpha + \beta) + \cos(\beta - \alpha)$ in a book. Is it correct?

Tags: trigonometry

The identity should be $2\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) = \cos(\alpha + \beta) + \cos(\alpha - \beta)$, but in the book (see attached picture) states it as follows
$2\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) = \cos(\alpha + \beta) + \cos(\beta - \alpha)$. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: One thing to note is that the values of $\cos A \cos B$ and $\cos (A + B)$ are unchanged if you swap $A$ and $B$. Thus (provided the identity is correct) the value of $\cos (A-B)$ would also be unchanged by swapping $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cosine function is even: $\cos x = \cos (-x)$ for all $x$.  In particular, $$\cos (\alpha - \beta) = \cos (\beta - \alpha).$$

Answer (score 1):

It's correct. $\cos x = \cos(-x) \forall x \in \mathbb R$ which means $\cos(A-B) = \cos (B-A) \forall A,B \in \mathbb R$

Answer (score 0):

note that $$\cos(A+B)+\cos(B-A)=\cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B)+\cos(B)\cos(A)+\sin(A)\sin(B)=2\cos(A)\cos(B)$$